# Extract data from a div class with iMacros on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: mozilla, imacros

I need to extract data with iMacros on Mozilla Firefox. The data is contained in a `div` class as in the picture below. I need to extract the price value, e.g. `6.399`.

[image: sample code]

Here's the saved macro code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:6.399,00<SP>TL
```

I tried:

```
TAG Pos=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT: new-price EXTRACT=TXT
'or
TAG Pos=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT: "new-price" EXTRACT=TXT
'or
TAG Pos=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID: new-price EXTRACT=TXT
```

Unfortunately, they don't work and result in a `#enaf#`.

Answer (score 0):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:new-price EXTRACT=TXT
```

Try this code.

Comment: thank you so much. It almost happened. The current result is 6,399,6,399,006,399,6.399,00TL. Why it repeats 4 times. should be 6399 only one...